# If a target is slowed and prone, can he still take the crawl action?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, ranger, conditions

I am playing a ranger and I have both Hobbling Strike and World Serpent's Grasp. Say I use Twin Strike and both attacks hit. On the first hit I choose to forego Hunters Quarry to slow the target and on the second hit I knock the target prone. Can the slowed, prone target still take a crawl action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They can crawl while slowed, however they will only move 1 square (assuming nothing else is affecting their speed).

Slowed is a condition that changes their speed to 2.<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=143)]</sup> Crawl is a move action that allows one to move up to half one's speed.<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=326)]</sup> Since their speed is now 2, crawling would move them up to 1 square.